# definite integral where one of the bounds is a variable of the integrand

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Suppose:

\begin{equation}
f_1(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & , & x\in\left[-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\\
0 & , & x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\\
1 & , & x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right]\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

and,

\begin{equation}
f_2(x) = -\frac{x}{2} + \int_0^x{f_1(x)dx}
\end{equation}

show that,
\begin{equation}
f_2(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{x+\pi}{2} & , & x\in\left[-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\\
-\frac{x}{2} & , & x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\\
\frac{x-\pi}{2} & , & x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right]\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

This is the first I have seen a definite integral where one of the bounds is a variable of the integrand. Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: $\int_0^x f_1(x)dx$ is confusing : I hope you're not confusing the two different $x$, that are the bounds of the integral and the integrating variable in this case. Replace that with a more comfortable $\int_0^x f_1(t)dt$ instead. The term $\int_0^x f_1(x)dx$ cannot be made sense if if the two $x$ are the "same".

Comment: From the title, I thought this would be about things like $\int_0^x f(x,t)\,dt$ which is also an interesting question.